# Compare timestamps and update a flag column

Tags: sql, db2, duplicate-data

> I need to compare timestamps of the same key records and update the
>   "NEW_RECORD" column with 1 which have latest date in both records.

**For example record with Key 1, one record which have year 2013. This record's NEW_RECORD column should be set 0 to 1. Any help will be appreciable.**

> So the comparison should be between similar keys, and next step to
>   update the NEW_RECORD column. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example with a previous data and with the modified data.

Comment: I added a screen shot. This is the first time I'm facing this problem with my data and needs to fix it. What I want to do is to compare the CREATE_TS of each pair of identical keys and which is the latest by date, Update that record's NEW_RECORD from 0 to 1.

Comment: Which version/platform of DB2?  This should be _very_ similar to many of the existing "find/delete duplicates" questions.  How are you planning on using/what queries are you planning on running with this information?  Will you need to update this information again when a new record is answered?

Comment: @AngocA I added a screen shot. This is the first time I'm facing this problem with my data and needs to fix it. What I want to do is to compare the CREATE_TS of each pair of identical keys and which is the latest by date, Update that record's NEW_RECORD from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Its DB2 9 LUW, And no it is not like other find/delete duplicates. I have to assign new key to each pair. And each record from a pair which has an older CREATE_TS is Ok. The new key needs for the latest record from each pair.

Comment: ... then `NEW_RECORD` (and it's value) is essentially unimportant.  Insert the later records to get the new keys with a "find duplicates" `SELECT`, then just `DELETE` the duplicates afterwards.  In any case, what part of your current statement isn't working/what errors is it throwing?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I don't want to delete any record from my data it is just the "key" which gets duplicated. I just have to differentiate between each pair of "key" and mark a flag for any of the record and then I'll give one of them a new key. This is all I want to do. I know how to find duplicates that's why I'm showing the extract of my duplicated data from the table.

Comment: There is no "DB2 9 LUW". It can be 9.1, 9.5, 9.7 or 9.8.

Comment: @mustaccio Can you advise any solution for this particular problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update 
   (select * 
    from 
      (select 
         t.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by somekey order by create_ts desc) rn 
       from test t) 
    where rn = 1) 
set new_record = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Mustaccio for your answer. If you please take a look on my attempt. I wrote following query yesterday and my query missing 10 records. However your query exactly dividing the total numbers by 2. So looks like that your query is correct. 

`select a.* from table_dup a inner join table_dup b 
on a.key = b.key and a.create_ts < b.create_ts;`